# error occured in Alamofire librarys request.swift file - "Ambiguous use of Task" after updating to xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3, alamofire

[image: Ambiguous use of Task]

I have updated my Xcode to Xcode 8.1 before upgradation it was working fine but after upgradation I have converted swift 2.3 to swift 3.0 and added updated alamofire library. But it was giving error in `request.swift` file of Alamofire.

Comment: You should update alamofire to the latest release

Comment: i have updated alamofire to latest 4.0

Comment: but it was not working

Answer (score 1):

i found it.

Request.swift >>

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
        //name: Notification.Name.Task.DidSuspend,
        name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "org.alamofire.notification.name.task.didSuspend"),
        object: self,
        //userInfo: [Notification.Keys.Tasks: task]
        userInfo: ["org.alamofire.notification.key.task": task]
    )

    NotificationCenter.default.post(
        //name: Notification.Name.Task.DidCancel,
        name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "org.alamofire.notification.name.task.didCancel"),
        object: self,
        //userInfo: [Notification.Keys.Tasks: task]
        userInfo: ["org.alamofire.notification.key.task": task]
    )
```

SessionDelegate.swift >>

```
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            //name: Notification.Name.Task.DidComplete,
            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "org.alamofire.notification.name.task.didComplete"),
            object: strongSelf,
            //userInfo: [Notification.Keys.Tasks: task]
            userInfo: ["org.alamofire.notification.key.task": task]
        )
```

edit another same code. maybe 4 ~ 5 function.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used used 'import Alamofire'. Comment that import out, build, then uncomment the import. Then retry compiling.

Comment: yes, for me too, this trick worked, but I had to comment the Alamfire code also, then  uncomment. (Because it has to compile successfully). 
And for me the issue starts when I close and open the project next day.
Anybody explain me why it happens ?